# convert a multi-dim array which stored as a string from Pandas df to a numerical array

Tags: python, string, pandas

When I tried to save a two-dim array as pandas dataframe, somehow it was written as a string:

```
df=    
                                        data
0 '[[0.125 0.09]\n [1.2 0.5] \n [0.25 0.99]]'
```

Ideally, I would like to get back as:

```
df.data=

np.array([[0.125, 0.09], [1.2 0.5], [0.25, 0.99]])
```

Is there a possible way to do so? I it a very lengthy and time consuming to re-run the code again so I'm trying to get the most from this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `eval` function in combination of `np.array`

```py
import numpy as np    
data = '[[0.125 0.09]\n [1.2 0.5] \n [0.25 0.99]]'
string_processed = data.replace("\n", "").replace("  ", " ").replace(" ", ",")
df = np.array(eval(string_processed))
```